# How to share plugin created database tables between two WordPress sites

Tags: database, wp-config, shared-user-tables

I have two WordPress installs. One is a subdomain (Blog 2) and the other is the root domain (Blog 1). All tables are installed in same database. I am already sharing the users table, but am also trying to share a few plugin created database tables. Is this possible?

I used the following code in my wp-config to share the user tables:

```
define(CUSTOM_USER_TABLE,'wp_users');
define(CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE,'wp_usermeta');
```

Is there a similar code to share plugin tables between sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that all you have to do is find where the database is returned (in my case it is wp-init.php) and change the prefix to reflect the shared database:

```
$wpdb->prefix="wp_";
```

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT EVER DO THIS. MODIFYING WORDPRESS CORE FILES WILL GET YOU IN A LOT OF TROUBLES WHEN YOU UPDATE IT